# undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.students.pay')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I have a test like this:

```
it('calls the stuFun method', function () {
     $scope.stuFun();
     expect($scope.stuFun).to
            .have.been.calledOnce;
     expect($scope.students.pay).to.not.equal(null);
     assert.isNotTrue($scope.students.pay)

});
```

Below is my controller function:

```
$scope.stuFun = function() {
    $scope.students.pay = false;
};
```

Why am i getting the below error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.students.pay')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is attached below:

```
it('calls the stuFun method', function () {
     $scope.students = {};
     $scope.stuFun();

     expect($scope.stuFun).to
            .have.been.calledOnce;
     expect($scope.students.pay).to.not.equal(null);
     assert.isNotTrue($scope.students.pay)

});
```

Now run it, it should work.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to mock such service... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227705/undefined-is-not-an-object-in-angular-js-service