# undefined is not an object in Angular.js service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I have a method like this in my `service`

```
 angular.module('App')
  .factory("AppService", [function() {

    var _admin;

    return {
        get admin() {
          return _admin;
        },
     };
  }]);
```

In my `controller` i am using it like this:

```
$scope.show = function(){
        return AppService.admin === 0 || (AppService.admin !== 0 && AppService.admin === true);
};
```

When i am trying to test the `function`, i am getting an error like below:

```
it('calls the showAutoPay method', function () {
    $scope.show();
    expect($scope.show).to
           .have.been.calledOnce;
    expect(service.admin).to.not.equal(null);
    assert.equal(service.admin, '0');
});
```

I am also not sure how to mock the `AppService` which has the `get` and `set` methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your beforeEach you would inject the service like this

```
var AppService;
 beforeEach(inject(function(_AppService_) {
   AppService = _AppService_;
}));
```

and in your test you can mock using jasmine like this

```
spyOn(AppService, 'getAdmin').andCallFake(function() {
  // return whatever you want
        return 0;
  });


// then the expect would be like
expect(AppService.getAdmin).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

More about jasmine's spies http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: getAdmin is not a function... its a setter/getter get admin() {}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what are you looking for:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function(AppService) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.service = AppService;

      vm.service._admin = 10;

      vm.random = function() {
        vm.service._admin = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        console.log('AppService obj => ', AppService._admin);
      };
    })
    .factory('AppService', function() {
      var admin;
      this.appService = {
        get _admin() {
          return admin;
        },
        set _admin(val) {
          admin = val;
        }
      };

      return this.appService;
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <button type="button" ng-click="main.random()">Change value</button>
  <span ng-bind="main.service._admin"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I completely misunderstood your question. Does your factory works well then? Do you want just know how to test it?

Comment: Yes, my factory works... i just want to know how to test the factory... which is injected in my controller...